# How to list unpushed Git tags

Tags: git, git-remote, git-tag

I'd like to see which tags I have locally that aren't available on a particular remote. How can I do this? I know I can do `git push --tags` to push all of them. However, if there are some tags that I don't want pushed, how to I make sure I haven't missed some?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the following to see the tags that exist locally but not in the specified remote:

```
git show-ref --tags | grep -v -F "$(git ls-remote --tags <remote name> | grep -v '\^{}' | cut -f 2)"
```

Note that `git ls-remote` shows both the annotated tag and the commit it points to with `^{}`, so we need to remove the duplicates.

An alternative is to use the `--dry-run`/`-n` flags to `git push`:

```
git push --tags --dry-run
```

This will show what changes would have been pushed, but won't actually make these changes.

Comment: Since you're using the output of `git ls-remote` to filter out from the `show-ref`, there's not much harm in leaving the `^{}` lines in. That leaves us with a slightly simpler: `git show-ref --tags | grep -v -F "$(git ls-remote --tags origin | cut -f 2)"`

Comment: This is the exact same command except with `<remote name>` replaced with `origin`. Use this to copy/paste: `git show-ref --tags | grep -v -F "$(git ls-remote --tags origin | grep -v '\^{}' | cut -f 2)"`

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I am using a variant of this with the 'comm' command:

```
comm -23 <(git show-ref --tags | cut -d ' ' -f 2) <(git ls-remote --tags origin | cut -f 2)
```

I am using it as a git alias in .gitconfig, with proper bash quoting like this:

```
[alias]
    unpushed-tags = "!bash -c \"comm -23 <(git show-ref --tags | cut -d ' ' -f 2) <(git ls-remote --tags origin | cut -f 2)\""
```

Comment: `comm -23 <(git ls-remote --tags .) <(git ls-remote --tags origin)`.  You can specify repos by local path or url or by git's extended url-style transport methods.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the accepted answer from Ben Lings missed unpushed tags which partially matched remote tags; for example unpushed tag "snowball" would not be listed if there was a remote tag called "snowba" or "snow".

I made a version that checks for exact name matches between local tags in the currently checked out branch and tags in the remote repo to find unpushed tags:

```
comm -23 <(echo "$(git tag --list)") <(echo "$(git ls-remote --tags -q | grep -v '\^{}' | cut -f 2 | cut -d '/' -f 3-)") | paste -s -d " " -
```

And if you only want to check for unpushed tags in the currently checked out branch:

```
comm -23 <(echo "$(git tag --merged)") <(echo "$(git ls-remote --tags -q | grep -v '\^{}' | cut -f 2 | cut -d '/' -f 3-)") | paste -s -d " " -
```

Here that same query for unpushed tags in the current branch is spilt up into multiple statements for use in a bash script (and for increased clarity):

```
local_tags_in_current_branch="$(git tag --merged)"
remote_tags="$(git ls-remote --tags -q | grep -v '\^{}' | cut -f 2 | cut -d '/' -f 3-)"
unpushed_tags=`comm -23 <(echo "$local_tags_in_current_branch") <(echo "$remote_tags") | paste -s -d " " -`
```